# How to pass variable from one function to another and display via shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to pass a variable from one function to another and displaying via a shortcode on the front end. This is my code

```
          function user_last_logout(){
          global $userr;
          $userr = 'hi';

          } 

          function get_logout_time(){
          global $userr;
          echo $userr;  
          }
          add_shortcode('lastlogn','get_logout_time');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the return of the function be the variable that you want, and then just call it inside the other function. Like so:

```
function user_last_logout()
{
    return 'hi';
}

function get_logout_time()
{
    echo user_last_logout();
}

add_shortcode('lastlogn','get_logout_time');
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: the idea is to be able to get different events like user id, ip using different functions and then sending it to a log file.

Comment: @Landry regarding the idea you mention, if you want help, please create another question, so we can help you.

Comment: this is my question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348470/how-to-write-different-events-from-different-functions-in-my-file-to-a-log-file please help me if you can